# Javascript - searching for specific characters used in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a program that will allow me to input shorthand names for specific commands in the database, something like this:

```
ID I(20) AI NN PK, name VC(255), story T
```

Then I have a map in which these are based from:

```
    var keys = {
        'PK' : 'PRIMARY KEY',
        'FK' : 'FOREIGN KEY'
    };

    var options = {
        'AI' : 'AUTO_INCREMENT',
        'NN' : 'NOT NULL',
        'D' : 'DEFAULT',
        'CT' : 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
    };
```

The problem that I have is searching for shorthand names present in a string and then replacing it with the values in the map.

The only solution that I can think of is by using regular expressions to look for the strings.

I currently have this regular expression:

```
(\bI\b|\bAI\b|\bPK\b|\bVC\b|\bT\b|\bNN\b)
```

Is this the only way to go? Can the regex above still be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use the split function. The way you're describing that seems quite cumbersome if you have to add something to the regexp.

I'd do something like

```
var shorthand = {
    "XX":"XXXXXX"
     ...
},
my_string = "ID I(20) AI NN PK, name VC(255), story T",
/* note that you can split using regexp like /\b/ if needed*/
splitted_str = my_string.split(" "),
result_str = "";
for (var i =0; i< splitted_str.length; i++) {
    /*You might want to use a regexp here to grab only the letters and still keep the parameters like the commas, parenthesis, number*/
    result_str += shorthand[splitted_str[i]] +" ";
}
/*And there you go, your request is in result_str.*/
```

**EDIT:** the loop with the regexp to keep the commas and so on. Note that you can adapt that if you want to match only upper case letters with something like `splitted_str[i].match(/^([A-Z]+)(.*)$/);`

```
var reResult;
for (var i =0; i< splitted_str.length; i++) {
    reResult = splitted_str[i].match(/^(\w+)(.*)$/);
    result_str += shorthand[reResult[1]] + reResult[2] +" ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can move the word boundary out of your alternation

```
\b(I|AI|PK|VC|T|NN)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use `replace` method of String in javascript;

pseudocode

```
newString = oldString.replace(regex, function(match, index){
    // find `replacement` for `match`  
    return replacement;
})
```